# expectation of the product of Gaussian kernels and their input

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, machine-learning

I was wondering if anybody knows how to solve: $$\mathbb{E}{\mathbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})}\left[ (\mathbf{x}{i} - \mathbf{z})(\mathbf{x}{j} - \mathbf{z})^\top \exp\left( - (\mathbf{x}{i} - \mathbf{z})^\top M (\mathbf{x}{i} - \mathbf{z}) -  (\mathbf{x}{j} - \mathbf{z})^\top M (\mathbf{x}{j} - \mathbf{z}) \right) \right].$$  Here $M$ is positive-semidefinite, and $\mathbf{x}i, \mathbf{x}j$ are constant vectors. I tried to solve this by just doing the integral $n$ times. However, you need to be able to solve $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x^n \cdot\exp(-ax - bx^2) \, dx. $$ You can do this by completing the square and making a change of variables, so you get $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(z-\frac{a}{2b}\right)^n \cdot\exp\left(-bz^2+\frac{a^2}{4b}\right) \,dz $$ which in theory you could expand solve by using binomial expansion and substituting in the $i$th moment of normal distribution. However, doing these repeatedly where a and b are some functions of the other variables don't seem like a promising lead to a closed form solution.

I'm asking on behalf of a friend, and this is his thought process. I want to do something with the exponential first if I were to work on the problem.

Comment: (i) By $\mathbb{E}{\mathbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})}$, do you mean the expectation assuming $\mathbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$? (ii) What are $\mathbf{x}{i}$ and $\mathbf{x}{j}$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry, I was a little unsure about that as well. (i), based on what I heard from my friend, I think that's the interpretation.  (ii) They are constant vectors. This is not my focus, so I'm not sure if there's any better way to write it. Feel free to edit the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Letting $I:=\mathbf I$, $a:=\mathbf xi$, $b:=\mathbf xj$, $N:=(4M+I)^{1/2}$, $c_1:=a^\top Ma+b^\top Mb$, $m:=2N^{-1}M(a+b)$, $c_2:=m^\top m/2=2(a+b)^\top M(4M+I)^{-1}M(a+b)$, completing the squares, using the substitutions $z=Ny$ and $y-m=v$,
and doing a bit of algebra, we see that the expectation in question is
$$\frac{e^{c_2-c_1}}{\det(4M+I)^{1/2}}(N^{-2}+N^{-1}mm^\top N^{-1}+ab^\top-am^\top N^{-1}-N^{-1}mb^\top). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Here one can get rid of $N$ and $m$ by noting that $N^{-2}=(4M+I)^{-1}$, so that $N^{-1}m=2(4M+I)^{-1}M(a+b)$ and hence $m^\top N^{-1}=2(a+b)^\top M(4M+I)^{-1}$.

---

**Details:** The expectation in question is
$$J:=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{\R^n}dz\,(z-a)(z-b)^\top e^{g(z)}, \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where
\begin{align}
g(z)&:=-(z-a)^\top M(z-a)-(z-b)^\top M(z-b)-z^\top z/2 \\ 
&=-z^\top(2M+I/2)z+2(a+b)^\top Mz-c_1 \\ 
&=-c_1-y^\top y/2+m^\top y \\ 
&=-c_1+c_2-v^\top v/2. \tag{3}\label{3} 
\end{align}
Also,
\begin{align}
(z-a)(z-b)^\top&=(N^{-1}(v+m)-a)(N^{-1}(v+m)-b)^\top \\ 
&=h(v):=N^{-1}(v+m)(v+m)^\top N^{-1}+ab^\top \\ 
&\qquad\qquad-a(v+m)^\top N^{-1}-N^{-1}(v+m)b^\top \\ 
&=N^{-1}vv^\top N^{-1}+N^{-1}mm^\top N^{-1} \\ 
&+N^{-1}vm^\top N^{-1}+N^{-1}mv^\top N^{-1} \\ 
&+ab^\top -a(v^\top+m^\top) N^{-1}-N^{-1}(v+m)b^\top \\
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}
and $dz=dy/\det N=dv/\det N=dv/\det(4M+I)^{1/2}$.

So, using \eqref{2}, \eqref{3}, and \eqref{3}, and letting $V$ denote a standard normal random vector in $\R^n$, we see that
\begin{align}
J&=\frac{e^{-c_1+c_2}}{\det(4M+I)^{1/2}}Eh(V). \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{align}
Noting finally that $EV=0$ and $EVV^\top=I$, from \eqref{5} we get the expression \eqref{1} for the expectation $J$ in question.